# Concatenate string with space mysql php

Tags: php, sql, concatenation, htmlspecialchars

```
$menunaam = "Lazy Dog" 
$resultmenus = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT menunaam FROM prijslijst WHERE menunaam='$menunaam'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultmenus,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" class=\"mnu\" name=\"mnnm\" value=".htmlspecialchars($row["menunaam"]).">";
```

This outputs

```
<input class="mnu" type="hidden" Dog="" value="Lazy" name="mnnm">
```

Then when i change it like this it works fine (with extra single quotation marks added):

```
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" class=\"mnu\" name=\"mnnm\" value='".htmlspecialchars($row["menunaam"])."'>";
```

Then i get a new problem. When i use a variable with the content: $menunaam= "lazy's"

```
<input class="mnu" type="hidden" s'="" value="lazy" name="mnnm">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whats wrong with:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" class="mnu" name="mnnm" value="'.htmlspecialchars($row["menunaam"]).'">';
```

or better yet:

```
printf('<input type="hidden" class="mnu" name="mnnm" value="%s">', htmlspecialchars($row["menunaam"]));
```